# How to access JSON Hierarchy in Java

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON coming from a server in the variable of StringBuffer called response which I can see in the output after making it toString().

```
[{"_id": "Grocery", "Categories": [{"Pulses and Grains": ["Dals"]}, {"Beverages": ["Juices", "Tea", "Coffee", "Soft Drinks"]}]}, {"_id": "Stationary", "Categories": [{"Chart Paper": ["A4 Size Chart Paper", "A3 Size Chart Paper"]}]}]
```

The code I have written till now which is not solving my purpose:

```
JSONArray ar=new JSONArray(response.
JSONObject jObject = ar.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject jObject = ar.getJSONObject(1);
String JObjectString=jObject.toString();
System.out.println("The JObject String "+JObjectString);
```

I need to store each and every element which includes "Pulses and Grains", "Dals", "Tea", "A3 size paper" etc. and every element in that array in a String variable. 
How can I access each and every element from the hierarchy since it is too nested.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JSONObject implements the Map interface, you can list all of its field name and values with method

```
jObject.entrySet()
```

If you know the name of the fields in advance, you can retrieve them by name:

```
JSONArray categories = jObject.get("Categories");
```

But I would rather suggest to use some nice JSON libraries such as google's Gson, so that you can just define your data classes and then automagically parse the JSON into a hierarchy of classes:

```
class Element {
   String _id;
   List<Category> categories;
   public Element(){}
}

class Category {
   private List<Entry> entries;
   public Category (){}
}

class Entry {
   private List<String> units;
   public Entry (){}
}
```

Then you can parse the json into objects:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Element[] elements = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Element[].class);
```